# Best practice for SOA message format with common+specific attributes in .NET

Tags: .net, wcf, architecture, soa

We need to design and describe an interface for a distributed system, parts of which will be implemented in .NET (most probably WCF). Besides to method-specific attributes each WS call will need to accept/provide some common attributes (e.g. authentication tokens or paging parameters for the request, or version and error info for the response). There will be tens to hundreds of different WS calls. We also expect to use WIF or similar technology for understanding SAML tokens and identity federation.

My preferred approach is (so far) to use a XML structure with some common header and a variable body for each call, e.g.

```
<Request>
   <Header>
     <Paging>...</Paging>
     ...
   </Header>
   <Body method="GetInvoices">
     <!-- specific attributes for GetInvoices web method -->
   </Body>
</Request>
```

**Questions:**

- Is this a good approach or do you recommend an alternative one?
- How to apply existing .NET technologies in order to simplify/automate dealing with this format as much as possible, namely

  - write the interface for a specific call and generate service/schema description for the body part(similar how WCF generates WSDL service description from the method contract)
  - parse the XML upon receipt, translate it into a call of the desired method with correct parameters (what I don't want to end up with is to have one big method with a big switch and 100s of cases...)

**UPDATE (1.7.2014)**

My question formulation has been perhaps somewhat vague. The real issue I am struggling with is to be able to apply ready-made .NET technologies for service generation (i.e. define a service contract and let VS generate WSDL service descriptions etc.) but at the same time make the message format flexible enough to allow for adding some out-of-band information which I intend to process separately.

For example I would like to have authentication data in the header (unsure yet in which form - possibly some authentication tokens, or SAML). Then I would like to intercept the request before it actually ends in the corresponding web method and reject it or set some context based on the authentication data, so that the web method can rely on the context. The same goes for paging in web methods where it is applicable, or success/failure messages for the response.

For sake of interoperability/generality I started with a "pure" XML approach, but now I can imagine a better solution would be to extend common SOAP message format like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header>
       <!-- out of band data -->
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <GetInvoices xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
          <!-- arguments  of GetInvoices() -->
      </GetInvoices >
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The question is then if this makes sense and whether it is implementable in WCF (how)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use standard SOAP message format with out-of-band bits and pieces added into the SOAP header.

For the implementation I use WCF extension mechanisms, namely custom behaviors, message inspectors and metadata export extensions. That way I am able to define all interfaces in code, mark the affected service/operation contracts with custom attributes and not only leverage existing WCF technology to generate WSDL, but also alter the WSDL generation to my specific needs, so that the service metadata contains all added informations for generating the service proxy clients.

As an overview article for this I recommend the MSDN Magazine article ["Extending WCF with Custom Behaviors"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sk-sk/magazine/cc163302%28en-us%29.aspx) and for an example with some .NET code how to do it [this](http://tintoy.snoscillator.net/2012/06/24/wcf-and-out-of-band-info/) article (the use case is similar to my example with paging parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I think with your requirement and based on your scenario description [Workflow Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456797%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
can be a very good match for your existing requirements specially if you are not sure of the contracts entirely, the contracts get implemented on the fly. This  facility gives you high level of flexibly specially if you are at the initial stages of your project and you are unsure of your Operation contracts. In addition you can combine WCF and WF to have a stateful service which can interact with the client who subscribe to the service.

Comment: I am sure about the method contracts - I need to specify the communication protocol before the actual implementation which I am not yet sure about. What I need is to draft such a format that it will be easy to use and describe (xsd, wsdl...) it later with existing technologies.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mechanism within System.ServiceModel which allows you to define a service data contract containing a base class with multiple subclasses.

This model is enabled via the ServiceKnownType attribute and is implemented so:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyBaseType
{
    ...
}

[DataContract]
public class MyDerivedType : MyBaseType
{
    ...
}

[ServiceKnownType(typeof(MyDerivedType))]
public class MyServiceImplementation : IMyServiceContract
{
    public MyBaseType GetADerivedType()
    {
        return new MyDerivedType();
    } 
}
```

However, as the number of "known" types grows (you said 100's), this list becomes huge and unwieldy, and adding new types means that you have to keep redeploying your service.

You can implement a resolver to handle this (as kind of described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), but it would still require some funky IoC stuff to actually load all the possible types at runtime and inject them to avoid the need to recompile with each change.

To be honest I think the concern here is that you say you're trying to define a "SOA message format" but really what does this mean?

If you're planning on having 300+ types exposed on a single service then to me this indicates that the service is composed at the wrong level - ie you'll have dynamic resolution at runtime of requests which will be interpreted into a lower level set of CRUD operations on some data.

This is akin to using the endpoint as some kind of repository and unless you're completely divorced from your data (like across the internet) I would say just go to the databse directly.

There's a reason a service contract is called a contract, and that is that in order to use the service, consumers must agree to implement a specific interface which caters to their specific needs, which are expressed by the service at operation level.

Ideally service operations should be composed at the level of Business Capability. In your example, *GetInvoices()* doesn't really explain to me what part or need of the business is being served. A better example would be

```
GetInvoicesForApprovalByHR(SomeInvoiceSelector x)
```

or even if the actual work to get the invoices was wrapped in an call which operates at a higher level, eg

```
StartHRApprovalWorkflowForUser(User x)
```

Examples at this level may be completely outside your current scope, and my apologies if this is so, but the point here is that interface composition is certainly one of the biggest influences on cost of ownership for distributed type solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see the update of my question for clarification.